# Stop highlighting trailing whitespace for Go files in Vim

Tags: vim, go, vim-syntax-highlighting

For some reason it seems the default for vim with Go files is to highlight trailing whitespace in red. In a way this is nice, but mostly I find it annoying because every time I type a space it starts as a red highlight. Is there a way to stop this behavior? I've only experienced this with Go files. Below is my vimrc, but I don't think I put anything there that would affect it.

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
set autoindent
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0
autocmd FileType go set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0
set formatoptions=tcroql
set relativenumber
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set smartindent
filetype indent on
```

Comment: I find this astonishingly irritating behaviour (nearly as bad as SO underlining the word "behaviour" as if it's misspelled).  It hides where the cursor is - particularly if you have showmatch switched on to show matching parens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `go.vim` Vim syntax file:

> ```
> "   There are some options for customizing the highlighting; the recommended
> "   settings are the default values, but you can write:
> "     let OPTION_NAME = 0
> "   in your ~/.vimrc file to disable particular options.
> ```

Put in your .vimrc

```
let g:go_highlight_trailing_whitespace_error=0
```

There are these other options:

> ```
> "   - g:go_highlight_array_whitespace_error
> "     Highlights white space after "[]".
> "   - g:go_highlight_chan_whitespace_error
> "     Highlights white space around the communications operator that don't
> "     follow the standard style.
> "   - g:go_highlight_extra_types
> "     Highlights commonly used library types (io.Reader, etc.).
> "   - g:go_highlight_space_tab_error
> "     Highlights instances of tabs following spaces.
> ```

If you still like the highlighting of trailing whitespaces but not during the typing, you can try

```
au InsertEnter *.go match goSpaceError /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
au InsertLeave *.go match goSpaceError /\s\+$/
```

Read more in [Highlight unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) from [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com).

Comment: It's also documented in `:help vim-go`.

Comment: On my system, I get "E149: Sorry, no help for vim-go".  Your terse comment is not just unhelpful, but wrong.